# Error in converting height from centimeters to feet inches

Tags: android

I write a method to convert height from centimeters to feet inches on click of a toggle button but when I try to click toggle button after entering the height in centimeter its throwing me error
  java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
Here is my code:

```
private void convertTofeetInches(EditText height_cm){
    String str = height_cm.getText().toString();
     int feet = (int) Math.floor(Integer.parseInt(str)/30.48);
    int inches = (int)Math.round((Double.parseDouble(str)/2.54) - ((int)feet * 12));
    Log.d("feet",String.valueOf(feet));
    Log.d("inches",String.valueOf(inches));
    enter_height.setText(""+feet + "'" +inches + "\"");


}
```

I think I am doing some mistake in type conversion. Can anybody please point it.

Comment: Try  double instead of int

Comment: @Tasos but I want to show only integer values not with decimal

Comment: but this creates decimals (Math.floor(Integer.parseInt(str)/30.48)) and you are trying to put in an int -- check here for proper use  -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137396/convert-decimal-feet-to-feet-and-inches

Comment: Here is the solution you need -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423348/height-conversion-cm-to-feet-and-inches-and-vice-versa

Comment: Which line of coffee causes the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
private void convertTofeetInches(String str) throws NumberFormatException{
    Double value = new Double(str);
    int feet = (int) Math.floor(value / 30.48);
    int inches = (int) Math.round((value / 2.54) - ((int) feet * 12));
    String ouput = feet + "' " + inches + "\"";
    enter_height.setText(ouput);
}
```